# Linear calculation of time in excel

Tags: excel, function, time, average

I have a column containing time (s) in excel. But the problem is that there are duplicate time values and a given time could be repeated "n" times. What I'm trying to achieve is devide the time step linearly. So as you can see below 0.02 was repeated 3 times (i.e. n=3), so ideally I would want to find the difference between 0.02 and 0.01 and then divide that by n. so the first time value after 0.01 would be = 0.01333 which can be worked out as follows (0.02-0.01)/n then 0.01+n.
The problem is n is not constant and could have any value between 2 and 10.
Please find a sample of the data below.

```
time (s)
0.00
0.01
0.02
0.02
0.02
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
```

Comment: Please show the results of your attempts at a solution also.

Comment: I'm trying to use the function "forecast.linear" but can't seem to get it to work properly.
Also, I can't find the function "interpolate" that I used to use use it back in the day. does the function "interpolate" still exists? or it has been replaced by another function?

Comment: I think it will be simpler for you to develop a solution using VBA or Power Query.  I'm not aware that there was ever an `INTERPOLATE` function in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list starts in cell A1, put this in cell B2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,A2,B1+(A2-AGGREGATE(14,6,($A$2:A2)/($A$2:A2<>A2),1))/COUNTIF(A:A,A2))
```